# how do i get my website "favicon" to be displayed on every page

Tags: html, apache, favicon

I know there are some questions like this but mine is different. I know how to get the favicon to show up but it only shows up on the home page not the other pages. How do I get it to show up on every page I create. I have tried putting another Favicon (same one) just a copy of it into the folder that holds the html pages but that did not work.

Using:

Html

apache

bravenet

Website: [www.securityfenceonline.com](http://securityfenceonline.com)

Answer (score 1):

Just place the favicon.ico file in the root of your website.

Answer (score 0):

creating the favicon as favicon.ico in the root of your website should works.

Related info: 
If you want look your new favicon in chrome...
chrome save the favicon and dont erase if you reload the cache.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/zXlEW0ZFErY

Comment: yes, i can look a favicon in your site. If you dont look it try with other navigator

Comment: i tried putting it in the root folder dint work

Comment: I dont know bravenet, but only the sourcecode of home its html good formed, i think maybe its the problem. https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.securityfenceonline.com%2Findex%2FPages%2FFENCES.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: look the bravenet documentation http://resources.bravenet.com/articles/design/graphics/how_favicons_work/  but if you look your sourcecode... you dont have <html></html><body></body><head></head> elements in your pages only in home, and you have elements of the head like in all the page.

Comment: if you want, you will try adding : <link rel="icon" href="http://securityfenceonline.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://securityfenceonline.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> in the head of all of your pages.